# Structured Streaming with Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

Can I create multiple batches in structured streaming with only one file with continuous data in it?

I have created multiple batches with multiple input files. But, now I want to generate multiple batches with new data with only one file having continuous incoming data in it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, this could be one way to split one stream into N streams.

```
from pyspark import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from functools import reduce
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql.types import *

sc = SparkContext('local')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
sqlContext.setConf("spark.streaming.backpressure.enabled", True)

input_file = "../data/salaryDirForStreaming"

my_schema = StructType([StructField('Column1', StringType(), True),
                        StructField('Column2', StringType(), True),
                        StructField('Column3', StringType(), True),
                        StructField('21-Jun', StringType(), True)])


def printBatch(df: DataFrame, i: int):
    print(f"Batch = {i} processing now")
    list_batch = df.collect()
    print(list_batch)
    print("end of mini-batch processing")
    return None


csvDF = sqlContext.readStream \
    .format("csv") \
    .option("header", True) \
    .schema(my_schema) \
    .load(input_file)
very_large_number = 423523644121

csvDF = csvDF.withColumn("randomInt", F.floor(F.rand() * very_large_number))

no_of_streams = 12

stream_list = []
for ii in range(no_of_streams):
    stream_ii = csvDF.filter(F.col('randomInt') % no_of_streams == ii)
    stream_list.append((f'stream_{ii}', stream_ii))

streamingQuery = stream_list[0][1].writeStream \
    .foreachBatch(printBatch) \
    .trigger(availableNow=True).start()

streamingQuery.awaitTermination()
```

Output of above code :

```
Batch = 0 processing now
[Row(Column1='A ', Column2='A1 ', Column3='B5 ', 21-Jun='5000', randomInt=303417707940), Row(Column1='A ', Column2='A1 ', Column3='B7 ', 21-Jun='2770574045', randomInt=66096102564), Row(Column1='A ', Column2='A3 ', Column3='B1 ', 21-Jun='33812004035', randomInt=421582143120), Row(Column1='A ', Column2='A1 ', Column3='B6 ', 21-Jun='123374000907', randomInt=92141064804), Row(Column1='A ', Column2='A1 ', Column3='B7 ', 21-Jun='2770574045', randomInt=127023017880), Row(Column1='A ', Column2='A3 ', Column3='B1 ', 21-Jun='33812004035', randomInt=159922584972), Row(Column1='A ', Column2='A1 ', Column3='B1 ', 21-Jun='56804709552', randomInt=29966410008), Row(Column1='A ', Column2='A1 ', Column3='B9 ', 21-Jun='141321103', randomInt=158988781032)]
end of mini-batch processing
```

Following is an example of input file used :

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,21-Jun
A ,A1 ,B1 ,56804709552
A ,A1 ,B2 ,0
A ,A1 ,B3 ,8860695817
A ,A1 ,B4 ,346870273
A ,A1 ,B5 ,5000
A ,A1 ,B6 ,123374000907
A ,A1 ,B7 ,2770574045
A ,A1 ,B8 ,87593986976
A ,A1 ,B9 ,141321103
A ,A1 ,B10 ,52944455940
A ,A1 ,B11 ,364372804
A ,A2 ,B1 ,6580867882
A ,A3 ,B1 ,33812004035
A ,A1 ,B1 ,56804709552
A ,A1 ,B2 ,0
A ,A1 ,B3 ,8860695817
A ,A1 ,B4 ,346870273
A ,A1 ,B5 ,5000
A ,A1 ,B6 ,123374000907
A ,A1 ,B7 ,2770574045
```